# É possível "inflar" um layout dentro de uma View ou FrameLayout?

Tags: android

É possível inflar um layout (chamarei de A) que possui seu xml completo dentro de uma View ou FrameLayout que está contido em outro layout (xml)?

Por exemplo, a tela montada através do layout A ficaria delimitada pela View do layout B. Sei que há a opção de fazer um include, mas esse não é o objetivo.

Comment: Não sei ficou muito claro, mas existe a `ViewStub` que nada mais é que um `include` dinâmico. Você consegue definir o `resource` em tempo de execução e podendo nem ser inflado se for o caso. Poderia colocar uma `ViewStub` dentro da `View` que está em B e inflar ela com A.

Comment: @Wakim eu tinha me esquecido da ViewStub. Vou verificar se com ela consigo realizar o que desejo.